# Typescript how access method from other class in constructor?

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection

I have 2 class `UserLogic` and `UserModel` I want to access method of `UserModel` inside `UserLogic` constructor... How can I do that?

```
import { UserModel, ItUser } from '../../models/user.model';

export class UserLogic {

    public user: ItUser;

    constructor() {
        //UserModel is singleton class
        this.user = UserModel.model().user;
        console.log(this.user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is UserModel an exported class?

Comment: UserModel is exported....

Answer (score 0):

> I want to access method of UserModel inside UserLogic constructor... How can I do that

According to your code you have access to an instance of `UserModel`. So just call the method e.g. `foo`:

```
import { UserModel, ItUser } from '../../models/user.model';

export class UserLogic {

    public user: ItUser;

    constructor() {
        this.user = UserModel.model().user;


        // Just call the method. eg.
        this.user.foo(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: No this is instance: `UserModel.model()`